# how to flip through the results of a database-query

Tags: android

I want to display the results of a database-query. Every row consists of many fields, a single row will fill the whole screen. Using gestures (left, right) I want to select the previous/next row (flip through the results). Something like Gallery does for images. Or a ListView with exactly one item per screen and horizontal scrolling.

Is there a simple solution, like some sort of collection-widget with an adapter? If not, how do I intercept the gestures to move the cursor and fill in the new values?

Thanks in advance, Bernhard

Comment: Actually, I have seen some code-snippets using ViewPager, but that code flips between different views. Im my case, I have a single view and I only want to change the data shown in the view. ViewPager could possibly do it, but i haven't found a complete example. Could you maybe provide a link?

Comment: Well if each row has different content, it is a different view only with the same layout.